# Mouse and Keyboard not working after reinstalling ubuntu-desktop

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu-16.04, linux-device-driver, hardware, system-administration

At first I got an error message,when I booted my system.

**The system is running in low-graphics mode.Your screen, graphics cards, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.**

I pressed  Ctrl +Alt+F1 and  entered into  terminal .Then I did the following commands.

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

`sudo shutdown -r now`

But after that ,even though error message was not showing when rebooted , my laptop's keyboard and mouse were not working.But external keyboard and laptop worked.My current Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the `xserver-xorg-input-all` package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
```

Comment: did you do `startx` after that?

Comment: what is that used for?

Comment: It will start the x-session after you've installed the xserver